# Try to make the_image.style.left = x_position; but log show the unequal result

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a simple program I want to test setTimeout function, but doesn't work. I can't understand when I printed out "the_image.style.left" It always shows 0, but x_position increase one every loop. I have examined many times, but I can't find why? Can you tell what's the problem? Thanks a lot.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>setTimer</title>
    <script>
      var the_timer,the_image,x_position = 0;
      function move_left(){
        console.log("move_left() is running");
        the_image = document.getElementById('cat');
        console.log(the_image);
        x_position = x_position + 1;
        console.log(x_position);
        the_image.style.left = x_position;
        console.log(the_image.style.left);
        the_timer = setTimeout(move_left,50);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="move_left()">
    <img id="cat" src="7.png" style="height:150px;position:absolute;left:0">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `px` or other CSS unit in order to get desire result. 
As you are changing the CSS through JS. CSS `left` property always need a unit.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>setTimer</title>
    <script>
      var the_timer,the_image,x_position = 0;
      function move_left(){
        console.log("move_left() is running");
        the_image = document.getElementById('cat');
        console.log(the_image);
        x_position = x_position + 1;
        console.log(x_position);
        the_image.style.left = x_position+"px";
        console.log(the_image.style.left);
        the_timer = setTimeout(move_left,50);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="move_left()">
    <img id="cat" src="7.png" style="height:150px;position:absolute;left:0">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have considered it.

Comment: I have added description. Please keep in mind that. :)